# loading binary data into a structure

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fill a structure (does not have to be an actual struct), with data loaded from a byte[].

There are many different data structures in the byte[], one of them is a string, which is declared as:

```
UInt16 stringLenght
byte[stringLenght] zeroTerminatedString
```

I 'c' language this could be handled by declaring a fixed size struct, and instead of a the struct containing the actual string, make a pointer to the string.

Something like:

```
UInt16 stringLength
char* zeroTerminatedString
```

Is there a (smart) way to do something similar in c#? I mean loading binary data from a file/memory and filling it into a structure?

Regards
Jakob Justesen

Comment: Your proposed C code is faulty so your chances of converting it to C# are doomed!

Comment: It depends. How many data records?  How big are they?

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you'd declare it in C.  If the record in the file contains a string then you'd declare the structure similar to:

```
struct Example {
    int mumble;   // Anything, not necessarily a string length
    char text[42];
    // etc...
};
```

The equivalent C# declaration would look like:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private struct Example {
        public int mumble;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 42)]
        public string text;
        // etc...
    }
```

You'd normally use BinaryReader to read the data.  But it cannot handle strings like this directly, you have to read them as a byte[] and do the string conversion yourself.  You also cannot take advantage of the declarative syntax, you have to write a call for each individual member of the struct.

There's a workaround for that, the Marshal class already knows how to convert unmanaged structures to managed ones with the PtrToStructure() method.  Here's a generic implementation, it works for any blittable type.  Two versions, a static one that reads from a byte[] and an instance method that was optimized to repeatedly read from a stream.  You'd use a FileStream or MemoryStream with that one.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class StructTranslator {
    public static bool Read<T>(byte[] buffer, int index, ref T retval) {
        if (index == buffer.Length) return false;
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        if (index + size > buffer.Length) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try {
            IntPtr addr = (IntPtr)((long)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject() + index);
            retval = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(addr, typeof(T));
        }
        finally {
            handle.Free();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Read<T>(Stream stream, ref T retval) {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        if (buffer == null || size > buffer.Length) buffer = new byte[size];
        int len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
        if (len == 0) return false;
        if (len != size) throw new EndOfStreamException();
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try {
            retval = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        }
        finally {
            handle.Free();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private byte[] buffer;
}
```

Untested, hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

The [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) should be able to do this for you.

Note that this can only be done to a struct and you will probably need to use the [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) attribute.

I'm not 100% sure on how to handle the string or arrays, but [BStrWrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.bstrwrapper.aspx) or [ArrayWithOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.arraywithoffset.aspx) MIGHT help, also keep on the lookout for similar classes/attributes (I know I have done stuff like this before for binding to native functions).