# Converting VB6 Custom Type (with Fixed Length Strings) to VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have upgraded some VB6 code, which uses fixed length strings in custom types, to VB .NET by using the UpgradeWizard and am having trouble with the use of the LSet method that I was hoping someone could help me out with.

The Existing VB6 code (type declarations);

```
Public Type MyType
    PROP1       As String * 15
    PROP2       As String * 25
End Type

Public Type MyTypeBuffer
    Buffer As String * 40
End Type
```

Example usage;

```
LSet instOfMyTypeBuffer.Buffer = ...
LSet instOfMyType = instOfMyTypeBuffer
```

What would be an appropriate way to upgrade this to .NET?

Using the UpgradeWizard, I get the following;

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
 _
Public Structure MyType
    <VBFixedString(15),System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst:=15)> _
    Dim PROP1 As FixedLengthString

    <VBFixedString(25),System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst:=25)> _
    Dim PROP2 As FixedLengthString

    Public Shared Function CreateInstance() As MyType
        Dim result As New MyType
        result.PROP1 = New FixedLengthString(15)
        result.PROP2 = New FixedLengthString(25)
        Return result
    End Function
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
 _
Public Structure MyTypeBuffer
    <VBFixedString(CLVHDR_REC_LENGTH),System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst:=40)> _
    Dim Buffer As FixedLengthString
    Public Shared Function CreateInstance() As MyTypeBuffer
        Dim result As New MyTypeBuffer
        result.Buffer = New FixedLengthString(40)
        Return result
    End Function
End Structure
```

FixedLengthString is coming from the namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.

Where the Upgrade Wizard fails is when it comes to LSet. It produced the following;

```
instOfMyTypeBuffer.Buffer = LSet(...)
instOfMyType = LSet(instOfMyTypeBuffer)
```

Which fails to compile, giving these errors;

> Value of type 'String' cannot be
>   converted to
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString'
>
> Argument not specified for parameter
>   'Length' of 'Public Function
>   LSet(Source As String, Length As
>   Integer) As String'
>
> Value of type 'MyTypeBuffer' cannot be
>   converted to 'String'

So, I can use ToString() to get part of the way there, but there is still the issue of the LSet method call itself. What should I do to recreate the original functionality? Has the Upgrade Wizard given me a totally inappropriate conversion, or is it salvageable into something usable?

Comment: It isn't salvageable, this form of LSet is no longer supported because it would generate unverifiable code.  Ditch the fixed length strings.

Comment: @Hans You are correct in general about [LSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266163%28v=VS.60%29.aspx). However here I think `LSet` was just being used as a bizarre way to do simple string manipulations. I think it's easy to [recode the manipulations in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864422/converting-vb6-custom-type-with-fixed-length-strings-to-vb-net/3865910#3865910)

Comment: I posted earlier about a similar problem, maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863191/loading-binary-data-into-a-structure/3863658#3863658

Comment: @Hans your other answer looks excellent for the general case. This is a special case where LSet is being abused to split up a record made of fixed-length strings.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I took at look at your other answer and it worked well. However, as I explained in my comment to MarkJ's answer, I decided to rework the code back to the safe world. Thanks for your suggestions, I've learned quite a bit from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSet is a rather quirky statement in VB6: see [description in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266163%28v=VS.60%29.aspx).

- When used on strings, it left-aligns the string in the original string and replaces any leftover characters with spaces.
- When used on user-defined types, it just copies the memory from one user-defined type over the other, even if they had different definitions. This is not recommended.

It's being used in a particularly quirky way in the code you have.

1. `LSet instOfMyTypeBuffer.Buffer = ...`
   This is redundant both in the VB6 and the migrated Vb.Net. When you assign a new value to a fixed-length string, it always pads out with spaces anyway!
   So just change to this (in either VB6 or VB.Net)
   `instOfMyTypeBuffer.Buffer = ...`
2. `LSet instOfMyType = instOfMyTypeBuffer`
   More interesting. This copies the memory from an instance of one type into an instance of another type, with no checks. **Gulp!**
   Looking at the definitions of the types, I think this simply puts the first 15 characters from `instOfMyBuffer` into `instOfMyType.PROP1` and the remaining 25 characters into `instOfMyType.PROP2`.
   I have occasionally seen this used as an ugly way of processing fixed-length string records read from a file. For example the first fifteen characters might be a person's first name, and the next 25 the last name.
   You could just replace with this code (in either VB6 or VB.Net).
   `instOfMyType.PROP1 = Left(instOfMyBuffer.Buffer, 15)`
   `instOfMyType.PROP2 = Mid(instOfMyBuffer.Buffer, 16)`

Hans suggested ditching the fixed-length strings. If that's easy - and it depends on the rest of your code base, it *might* be easy, or it *might* be hard - it's good advice.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - this is legacy code that I've been tasked with migrating and it's my first experience with this kind of data handling. I did a bit of research myself and came across a C# solution; http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/gil_structs.aspx Do you think something like this might also be appropriate? I guess that it's still not really in the spirit of .NET, but do you think it might do the trick?

Comment: @C.McAtackney Good find - I think that might do the trick. Possibly it might need to "pin" the buffer to stop the .Net framework moving it part way through? Like Hans does in [his other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863191/loading-binary-data-into-a-structure/3863658#3863658). In any case it's still just as ugly, incomprehensible and potentially risky as the original code was! I would recommend using `Left()` and `Mid()` instead, or the .Net equivalent `.Substring()`

Comment: I implemented Hans' approach and it worked well. I then went back and scrutinised the original code and can't come up with any other explanation as to why LSet was used in this way other than convenience. As such, I've decided to implement my own FixedLengthString class and a parent type which maps the input string onto a Dictionary<string,FixedLengthString>. It works well, and I've included some use of String.PadRight(...) to recreate the original behaviour. Thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @C.McAtackney your own new class sounds like a nice clean replacement. I agree the original code must have been an ugly-unreadable/clever-performant trick for splitting out parts of a string buffer. Hans' approach is much more general, and I'm in awe of his knowledge of .Net internals, but ultimately in this case it's just an ugly-unreadable/clever-performant trick in .Net & even more risky because .Net moves memory around. I don't think your successors would have been pleased with it, in that distant day when you're somewhere else and the code is now someone else's legacy code assignment! :)