# Converting this code from vb6 to vb.net BigEndian to integer

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I did not write this vb6 code but I am responsible for converting it to vb.net. as I complete the rest of the applications conversion. I am looking for a way around using the Lset statements as they are no longer supported in vb.net

```
  Public Structure BigEndian
    Dim b1 As Byte
    Dim b2 As Byte
    Dim b3 As Byte
    Dim b4 As Byte
    Dim b5 As Byte
    Dim b6 As Byte
    Dim b7 As Byte
    Dim b8 As Byte
End Structure
Public Structure VBInteger <--This used to be Long in vb6
    Dim Value As Integer  <-- same here
End Structure

Private Function SwapBytes(theBytes() As Byte, index As Integer, Count As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ix As Integer
    Dim result(Count) As Byte
    Dim Bytes As BigEndian
    Dim tmp As VBInteger
    ix = Count - 1
    For i = 0 To (Count - 1)
        result(ix - i) = theBytes(index + i)
    Next
    Select Case Count
        Case 4
            Bytes.b4 = result(3)
            Bytes.b3 = result(2)
            Bytes.b2 = result(1)
            Bytes.b1 = result(0)
            LSet tmp = Bytes
        SwapBytes = tmp.Value
        Case 8
            Bytes.b8 = result(7)
            Bytes.b7 = result(6)
            Bytes.b6 = result(5)
            Bytes.b5 = result(4)
            Bytes.b4 = result(3)
            Bytes.b3 = result(2)
            Bytes.b2 = result(1)
            Bytes.b1 = result(0)
            LSet tmp = Bytes
        SwapBytes = tmp.Value
    End Select
End Function
```

This would be called from something like this:

```
Private Function GetQInt32() As Integer
    GetQInt32 = SwapBytes(Data, iStart, 4)
    iStart = iStart + 4
End Function
```

Comment: I would convert to binary representation (byte array), reverse the order of the array, and convert it to a number. This appears to have an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677073/how-to-rewrite-lset-from-vb6-in-vb-net-with-structure-types

Comment: Use BitConverter.ToInt32() or ToInt64() to replace LSet, you don't need the Structure.

Comment: You mean something like this??
    Select Case Count
            Case 4
                Bytes2(3) = result(3)
                Bytes2(2) = result(2)
                Bytes2(1) = result(1)
                Bytes2(0) = result(0)
                'Bytes.b4 = result(3)
                'Bytes.b3 = result(2)
                'Bytes.b2 = result(1)
                'Bytes.b1 = result(0)
                'LSet tmp = Bytes
                Return BitConverter.ToInt32(Bytes2, 0)