# How to marshal structs with unknown length string fields in C#

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

I get an array of bytes, I need to unmarshal it to C# struct.
I know the type of the struct, it has some strings fields.
The strings in the byte array appears as so: two first bytes are the length of the string, then the string itself.
I don;t know the length of the strings.
I do know that its Unicode!

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class User
{
  int Id;//should be 1
  String UserName;//should be OFIR
  String FullName;//should be OFIR
}
```

the byte array looks like so: 
00,00,01,00,
00,00,08,00,
4F,00,46,00,49,00,52,00,
00,00,08,00,
4F,00,46,00,49,00,52,00,

I also found this link with same problem unsolved:
[loading binary data into a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863191/loading-binary-data-into-a-structure)

Thank you all,
Ofir

Comment: Ofir, suggested edits are not meant as a means of communication, if you would like to add a comment or expand your question feel free.

Comment: How do you get the 1 from the byte array?  An `int` is 4 bytes, which would be `{00, 00, 01, 00}`, which isn't 1.

Comment: Please see my 'answer'.  I need more information.  Knowing the byte array isn't enough.  What does the native structure look like?

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with a `BinaryReader`. This would go along these lines:

```
Foo ReadFoo(Byte[] bytes)
{
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));
     foo.ID = reader.ReadUInt32();
     int userNameCharCount = reader.ReadUInt32();
     foo.UserName = new String(reader.ReadChars(userNameCharCount));

     int fullNameCharCount = reader.ReadUInt32();
     foo.FullName = new String(reader.ReadChars(fullNameCharCount));
     return foo;
}
```

Please note this will not work directly for the byte array example you provided. The char counts and the ID field are not in standard little endian or bigendian order. It could be that the fields are 16 bit, and that they are prepended with 16 bit padding fields. Who generated the this bytestream?

But the exact format isn't too important for this strategy, as you can just change `ReadInt32` into `ReadInt16`, reorder them, whatever, to make it work.

I am not to fond of the serializer attributes. That is because it couples your internal data structures to how it is exchanged. This breaks in case you need to support multiple versions of the dataformat.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer (yet) but is a question/comment with a sizable amount of code for feedback.  How do you interpret your byte array?  Break it down.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct Foo
{
    public int id;

    //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    //public string A;

    //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    //public string B;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] bits = new byte[] {
        0x00, 0x00, 
        0x01, 0x00, 
        0x00, 0x00, 
        0x08, 0x00,     // Length prefix?               
        0x4F, 0x00,     // Start OFIR?
        0x46, 0x00, 
        0x49, 0x00,     
        0x52, 0x00,     
        0x00, 0x00, 
        0x08, 0x00,     // Length prefix?
        0x4F, 0x00,     // Start OFIR?
        0x46, 0x00, 
        0x49, 0x00, 
        0x52, 0x00 };   

    GCHandle pinnedPacket = GCHandle.Alloc(bits, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    Foo msg = (Foo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
        pinnedPacket.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
        typeof(Foo));
    pinnedPacket.Free();
}
```